# C++ std::generate function always gives same values

Tags: c++, arrays, random, generator

I'm trying to fill an array with random values and I decide to use `std::generate` like so:

```
std::vector<double*> collection;

static std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device{}());
auto random = std::bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(lo, hi), mt);

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(collection), 10, [&]() {
    double *temp = new double[2];
    std::generate(temp, &temp[2], random); // this is the line in question
    return temp;
});
```

**Output:**

```
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
{7.43764, 5.70863}
```

Doing it this way will always give the same values for all arrays initialized as you can see, however changing it to use a for-loop, will always give random values for each array.

```
std::vector<double*> collection;

static std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device{}());
auto random = std::bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(lo, hi), mt);

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(collection), 10, [&]() {
    double *temp = new double[2];
    for (int t = 0; t < 2; t++)
        temp[t] = random();
    return temp;
});
```

**Output:**

```
{6.70092, 8.66923}
{8.73056, 9.05703}
{3.9088, 1.03048}
{9.67146, 6.65221}
{6.86209, 6.63852}
{4.16209, 2.99451}
{1.14352, 3.5196}
{5.83698, 9.68745}
{6.11013, 2.53315}
{4.72685, 6.59364}
```

Is this behaviour normal? Why or why not?

```
Ubuntu 14.10

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb added to question description

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `std::generate` copies the functor unless you wrap it in a `reference_wrapper`. For that matter, your `std::bind` call also copies `mt`.

Comment: @T.C., so the copying is what causes this? Can you elaborate? Thanks anyways, it worked well but would like to know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard library algorithms, including `std::generate`, are generally allowed to copy their function objects freely. (The one exception I know of is `std::shuffle`.) They usually take them by value, so each `generate` call uses a copy of `random`.

This wouldn't have been that bad, except that `std::bind` copies the bound arguments, so `random` itself holds a *copy* of the mt19937 engine `mt`, and so copying `random` *copies* that engine. As a result, each `generate` call will use a separate engine, and each of those engine will have the same initial state, so they will generate identical "random" numbers.

Use a `reference_wrapper` when you `bind`:

```
auto random = std::bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(lo, hi), std::ref(mt));
```

(Otherwise, calls to `random` will not change the state of `mt`, and repeat calls to this function will produce the same "random" values.)

Optionally, use a `reference_wrapper` for `generate` too:

```
std::generate(temp, &temp[2], std::ref(random));
```